# Why my Span tag content is showing in next line?

Tags: html, css

I want to add * for showing as mandatory fields. when I place span tag after input type text it is showing in same line.

```css
.holder_options_1 {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left: 11px;">
  <input type="text" name="tags" id="xyz">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span class="holder_options_1">*</span>
</div>
```

but when I place same span tag after input type file it showing in next line.

```css
.holder_options_1 {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left: 11px;">
  <input type="file" name="fileupload" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg" id="fileToUpload" style="height:33px">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span class="holder_options_1">*</span>
</div>
```

why it is coming like that?
I want that span tag also in same line. How to do that?please explain.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Based from the snippet, it is also in the same line

Comment: I have created snippet for you, there is no issue.

Comment: which bootstrap version you are using?

Comment: I think you code is correct it should be displayed in same line.. however you can use `display: inline-block` css for your input tag and span to display them in same line.

Comment: thank you vinit singh. display: inline-block is working.

Answer (score 0):

By default the span tag has a `display: inline`, his behaviour is like text. If you parent is too small the span go to the next line.